# Confused by Return in Array Recursion (java)

Tags: java, arrays, boolean, return

Given an array of ints, is it possible to divide the ints into two groups, so that the sums of the two groups are the same. Every int must be in one group or the other. Write a recursive helper method that takes whatever arguments you like, and make the initial call to your recursive helper from splitArray(). (No loops needed.)

This is a problem from coding bat that I am trying to figure out. I got really stuck so I found a solution but I am confused by the purpose of one line and confused completely by what the final return statement is doing. Thanks for your help!

```
public boolean splitArray(int[] nums) {

return splitArrayHelper(nums, 0, new int[nums.length], 0, 0, new int[nums.length], 0, 0); 
} 

private boolean splitArrayHelper(int[] nums, int n, int[] split1, int s1, int t1, int[] split2, int s2, int t2) { 

if (n == nums.length) 
 return t1 == t2; //returns true or false

split2[s2] = split1[s1] = nums[n]; // What is the purpose of this line?

return 
splitArrayHelper(nums, n + 1, split1, s1 + 1, t1 + nums[n], split2, s2, t2) || 
splitArrayHelper(nums, n + 1, split1, s1, t1, split2, s2 + 1, t2 + nums[n]); 
} //I don't know what this return statement is doing. How is the or statement decided?
```

Comment: The code is really confusing. Variable naming is not very clear.
However, I can see the algorithm is using recursion to solve this problem. The or "||" in the return statement simply or the two boolean returned by the recursive call.

Comment: I'm sorry. Your explanation of the return is not totally clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that we will have to split the original array into 2 arrays, called A and B, so for every number in the original array, that number will either belong to A, or B. We keep the sum of A (group1Total) and sum of B (group2Total) so far.

I would write my helper like below

```
    private static boolean splitHelp(int[] nums, int elementCount, int group1Total, int group2Total) {
            if (elementCount == nums.length) {
                return group1Total == group2Total;
            }

            return splitHelp(nums, elementCount + 1, group1Total+ nums[n], group2Total) //The element belongs to array A
|| splitHelp(nums, n + 1, group1Total, group2Total+ nums[n]) //or the element belongs to array B;
        }
```

Comment: How is the decision being made? I see that it either in the first array or the second but where is the actual criterion?

Comment: To visualize this, at every step, we have a number nums[n], and two sums: group1Total or group2Total. So we have two possibilities: either put nums[n] into group1Total, or put nums[n] into group2Total. For each possibility, we repeat the process for the next number in the array (nums[n+1]) using recursion.
In other word, we tried all 2^n possibilities.

Comment: So this gives us both possibilities until the final return statement is called in the if statement?

Comment: Yes, both possibilities would be on the stack until we reach the if statement

Comment: Tracing down the stack is an inefficient way to understand a recursive algorithm. You just have to understand the base step and the recursive call. Trying to understand the stack will just make the problem complicated.